# Click not working on RecyclerView items inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick, android-recyclerview, fragment

My application uses the following structure:

```
Activity > ViewPager > FragmentStatePagerAdapter > Fragment > RecyclerView
```

I've been using RecyclerViews fairly comfortably in the past, but for some reason I cannot get my RecyclerView items to register click events when placed inside a Fragment. My ViewHolder is as follows:

```
// ViewHolder Class for ExhibitAdapter
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView itemTitleTextView;
        public TextView itemDescriptionTextView;
        public NetworkImageView itemCoverPhoto;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemCoverPhoto = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.exhibitThumbnailNIV);
            itemTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.exhibitNameTV);
            itemDescriptionTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.exhibitDescriptionTV);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "Exhibit clicked");
                Exhibit currentExhibit = exhibits.get(getAdapterPosition());
                intent.putExtra(ExhibitContentActivity.EXHIBIT_ID , currentExhibit.getId());
                intent.putExtra(ExhibitContentActivity.EXHIBIT_COVER_URL , currentExhibit.getCoverPhotoUrl());

                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                        makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) adapterContext, itemView.findViewById(R.id.exhibitThumbnailNIV), "profile");

                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to launch detail activity with exhibit id: " + currentExhibit.getId());

                adapterContext.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());

            }
            catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "* Error: Adapter position exceeded the no. of items.");
            }
        }

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. I tried following the steps listed at: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments#fragment-listener to create a Fragment Interaction listener, but I'm not sure how I would implement this from within a RecyclerView's Adapter. Thanks in advance!

Comment: DId you figure out a solution to this?

Comment: @MichaelA. Yeah, the problem was simply that 1. my item layout was taking a little too long to draw and 2. I was handling the onClick logic within the ViewHolder class. I solved it by creating a listener interface in the fragment, calling that listener's onMyItemClick method in the ViewHolder's onClick and then implementing that listener in my Main Activity. This allowed me to define what to do when an item was clicked while efficiently bubbling up the click events to my main activity.

Comment: @ShahraizT. Hello , is there a sample code of your solution somewhere ? I have the same issue and your solution is what I need. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You should be setting your onClickListener in the onBindViewHolder method of your RecyclerView adapter, not in your ViewHolder. The problem is that ViewHolders are not actual views (thus you can't click on one), they are holders that bind to views and allow you to reuse those views for multiple list items to reduce the memory footprint of your app.

**RecyclerView.Adapter implemetation**

```
public MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourViewHolderClass> {
    .
    .
    .
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final YourViewHolderClass holder, int position) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do something!
            }
        });
        // Do you other view binding operations
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Be sure to store a copy of `itemView` locally in your view holder so that you can bind the OnClickListener to your list item's container.

**RecyclerView.ViewHolder implementation**

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView itemTitleTextView;
    public TextView itemDescriptionTextView;
    public NetworkImageView itemCoverPhoto;
    public View itemView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.itemView = itemView;
        itemCoverPhoto = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.exhibitThumbnailNIV);
        itemTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.exhibitNameTV);
        itemDescriptionTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.exhibitDescriptionTV);
    }
```

}

I hope this helps!

-Tom

Comment: Thanks Tom, but the reason I didn't have the onClickListener inside of my onBindViewHolder is because that would create a new View.OnClickListener every time and would take away from the performance benefits of using a RecyclerView. ViewHolder is created once, so it is standard practice to attach your onClickListener to it. This way, the data inside it changes in onBindView as much as needed and we get to use onClick functionality as well. The trouble is, my clicks won't work when inside a fragment. So I'm guessing the clicks need to be bubbled up to my activity.

Answer (score 0):

Does your itemView have any focusable views inside? If so, try to add `android:focusable="false"` to the xml of the view, It worked in ListView, but I am not sure if it is so in RecyclerView.